# How to check if mail already exists in database when using updateProfile () function

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I do not know how to implement a method in which when using the updateProfile () function, it checks the firestore if such mail already exists and then an error would pop up. I did a test method in MyAccount.vue, but it doesn't work, if I don't type anything and click, nothing updates, but that's not the point, I would like it to check if such mail exists.

./src/views/MyAccount.vue

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex';

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            user: {
                username: '',
                email: '',
                password: ''
            }
        };
    },

    computed: {
        ...mapState(['userProfile']),
    },

    methods: {
        updateProfile() {
            this.$store.dispatch('updateProfile', {
                username:
                    this.user.username !== ''
                        ? this.user.username
                        : this.userProfile.username,
                email:
                    this.user.email !== ''
                        ? this.user.email
                        : this.userProfile.email,
                password:
                    this.user.password !== ''
                        ? this.user.password
                        : this.userProfile.password
            });

            this.user.username = '';
            this.user.email = '';
            this.user.password = '';

            this.showSuccess = true;

            setTimeout(() => {
                this.showSuccess = false;
            }, 2000);
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

./src/store/index.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import * as fb from '../firebase';
import router from '../router/index';

Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        userProfile: {},
        notes: []
    },

    mutations: {
        setUserProfile(state, val) {
            state.userProfile = val;
        },

        setNotes(state, val) {
            state.notes = val;
        }
    },

    actions: {
        async updateProfile({ commit, dispatch }, user) {
            const userId = fb.auth.currentUser.uid;

            await fb.usersCollection.doc(userId).update({
                username: user.username,
                email: user.email,
                password: user.password
            });

            dispatch('fetchUserProfile', { uid: userId });
        },

        async fetchUserProfile({ commit }, user) {
            // fetch user profile
            const userProfile = await fb.usersCollection.doc(user.uid).get();

            // set user profile in state
            commit('setUserProfile', userProfile.data());

            // change router to dashboard
            if (router.currentRoute.path === '/login') {
                router.push('/');
            }
        }
    },
    modules: {}
});

export default store;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before updating, try this:

```
const current = await fb.usersCollection.where('email', '==', user.email).get()
if (current.empty === true) {
  // You are free to do the update, because the email is not in use already
}
```

Of course, this works best if you make sure to alway lowercase your emails before querying or storing them in the database

Comment: Thank you Simon. It is working. But I have a question. Because this only applies to the email, and what if I wanted to verify the username and email at the same time? I would have to make such a query 2x?

Comment: Yes, that would be 2 separate queries, as Firestore does not use OR in their queries for performance optimization. So IF username has to be unique, then you need an extra query to test for this.